# Sum of frequency of sublist

Tags: python-3.x

I have counted frequency of occurrence of sublists in a list. Now I want to sum all the frequencies to find out probability of a particular sublist in a list. How can I do this?

```
freq = [(key, len(list(x))) for key, x in groupby(sorted(data))]
length = len(freq)
for i in range(0,length):
   print(freq[i])
```

These are my sublists with their frequency of occurrence. I want to sum all these frequencies:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum of frequencies of your sub-lists as stored in `freq` would be:

```
sum_freq = sum(i[1] for i in freq)
```

The probabilities of the occurrences of the keys can be then turned into a dict:

```
{k: f / sum_freq for k, f in freq}
```

Comment: i want to count probability as well the code i have written isn't working can u please suggest what's the problem.for f in range(0,length):
    probability=freq[i]/b
    print(probability[i])

Comment: Sure. I've updated my answer with a solution to produce a dict of probabilities.

Comment: I am writing it this way "dict={k: f / b for k, f in freq}
print(dict)" and its not giving any output.b is my sum.

Comment: I see you're using lists such as `['aam', 'mov']` as keys. You should convert them to tuples so that they are hashable and can be keys of dicts: `{tuple(k): f / sum_freq for k, f in freq}`. It works in my testing.